# Angular 12 and custom pipes.... how to?

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-pipe

### Short form:

I get an error `The pipe 'getListItemText' could not be found`

### Long form:

I have a need to use a pipe to transform a series of data objects (a mildly complex json object) to an html string

This seems *ideal* for an angular pipe!

This pipe is very specific to this data, so everything is contained within the component directory:

The pipe (`get-list-item-text.pipe.ts`):

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'getListItemText'
})
export class GetListItemTextPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value.trim().split(/\s+/).length;
  }

}
```

(I'll make it more complicated & do what I want once I have the basic thing working)

The component *definition* (`descriptions.module.ts`):

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DescriptionsComponent } from './descriptions.component';
import { DescriptionResolver } from './description.resolver';
import { DescriptionService } from './description.service';
import { GetListItemTextPipe } from './get-list-item-text.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    DescriptionsComponent,
    GetListItemTextPipe,
  ],
  providers: [
    DescriptionResolver,
    DescriptionService,
  ]
})
export class DescriptionsModule { }
```

... and the fragment of html (`descriptions.component.html`) I'm working with:

```
          <li *ngFor="let section of notebook.description.sections" ><span \
                      [innerHTML]="section.prepend | getListItemText "></span></li>
```

If I run my tests (`ng test --watch=false`), I get an error `The pipe 'getListItemText' could not be found`:

```
Chrome Headless 96.0.4664.45 (Linux x86_64) DescriptionsComponent should init, call the DescriptionSelector service, and get a response FAILED
    Error: NG0302: The pipe 'getListItemText' could not be found!. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0302
    error properties: Object({ code: '302' })
    Error: NG0302: The pipe 'getListItemText' could not be found!. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0302
        at getPipeDef$1 (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:25804:1)
        at ɵɵpipe (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:25761:1)
        at DescriptionsComponent_section_21_li_7_Template (ng:///DescriptionsComponent.js:7:5)
        at executeTemplate (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9579:1)
        at renderView (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9383:1)
        at TemplateRef.createEmbeddedView (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:23036:1)
        at ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:23167:1)
        at node_modules/@angular/common/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/common.js:3340:1
        at DefaultIterableDiffer.forEachOperation (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:21569:1)
        at NgForOf._applyChanges (node_modules/@angular/common/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/common.js:3335:1)
Chrome Headless 96.0.4664.45 (Linux x86_64): Executed 49 of 62 (1 FAILED) (skipped 4) (0 secs / 0.217 secs)
Chrome Headless 96.0.4664.45 (Linux x86_64) DescriptionsComponent should init, call the DescriptionSelector service, and get a response FAILED
    Error: NG0302: The pipe 'getListItemText' could not be found!. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0302
    error properties: Object({ code: '302' })
    Error: NG0302: The pipe 'getListItemText' could not be found!. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0302
        at getPipeDef$1 (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:25804:1)
        at ɵɵpipe (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:25761:1)
        at DescriptionsComponent_section_21_li_7_Template (ng:///DescriptionsComponent.js:7:5)
        at executeTemplate (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9579:1)
        at renderView (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9383:1)
        at TemplateRef.createEmbeddedView (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:23036:1)
        at ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:23167:1)
        at node_modules/@angular/common/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/common.js:3340:1
        at DefaultIterableDiffer.forEachOperation (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:21569:1)
```

If I remove the pipe from the fragment of HTML, the tests pass fine.

Everything I've found implies this is a correct implementation, however it's obviously not.

What have I missed?

How do I specify, and then use, a custom pipe?

(just to note, I did try a top-level definition, and adding the pipe definition to the `app.module.ts` file.... same problem; and adding a `constructor` as suggected in [Getting 'Could Not Be Found' Error re: Custom Pipe in Angular 2 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265843/getting-could-not-be-found-error-re-custom-pipe-in-angular-2-app) makes no difference)

Comment: Looks like you have a issue with testing, Is it working with `ng serve`? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543374/angular-2-unit-test-custom-pipe-error-the-pipe-could-not-be-found) might help you

Answer (score 0):

Check live example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-new-f5hoeu?file=src/app/app.component.html

Create pipes.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ // import all pipes here
    GetListItemTextPipe 
  ],
  imports: [],
  exports: [ // import all pipes here
    GetListItemTextPipe 
  ]
})
export class PipesModule { }
```

import `PipesModule` in `app.module.ts` file inside `imports` array

import `PipesModule` in `descriptions.module.ts` file inside `imports` array

Comment: thanks for the reply, and for the live example. Two questions: 1) The path seems to be fixed: I can change the class name in `pipes.module.ts` (and the reference to it) - but as soon as I change the name of the `pipes` folder... everything breaks; and 2) I can't replicate locally - either just defining the import in just `app.module.ts` or also in my component's foo.module.ts file ... as you describe above.
What you have _looks_ logical, and if it works, is wonderfully extensible